# Series of integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a_n=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)^ndt$. Let

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$$
Prove that domain of definition of $S$ is $[-1,1)$. Calculate $S$ when $x\in[-1.1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the problem, you can switch the order of summation and integration and sum the geometric series to arrive at a fairly simple integral for $S(x)$:

$$\begin{align}
S(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{2-x-xt^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for direction. For me the hard part is to show that the summation is uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1):

We calculate convergent radius through $1/R =\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]a_n}$

Because $1\ge\frac{1+t^2} 2 \ge t$, so $1\ge\sqrt[n]a_n\ge \sqrt[n]{\int_0^1 t^ndt}=\frac1 {\sqrt[n]{n+1}}$
But  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt[n]{n+1}}=1$$ so $\ $ $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]a_n=1$ $\ $by comparison test

So the $S(x)$ is convergent on $(-1,1)$

At $x=-1$, we have $$S(-1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_n$$

This is a sign-alternating series, we will prove that $\{a_n\}$ is a monotone sequence and $\ lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$

From $\frac{1+t^2} 2 \le 1$, we have $${\left(\frac{1+t^2} 2\right)}^n \ge {\left(\frac{1+t^2} 2\right)}^{n+1}\  $$ and $\ a_n \ge a_{n+1}\ $ as a result. So $\{a_n\}$ is non-increasing sequence.

Also, $\frac{1+t^2} 2 \le \frac {1+t} 2$ implies $$0\le a_n\le\int_0^1 {\left(\frac{1+t} 2\right)}^n dt = {\frac2 {n+1}}.\left(1-\frac1 {2^{n+1}}\right)$$
But $\ lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac2 {n+1}}.\left(1-\frac1 {2^{n+1}}\right)=0$, so $\ lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$

Therefore $S(x)$ is convergent on $[-1,1)$, as we wanted

Now we can calculate $S(x)$ by the uniform convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac {1+t^2} 2\right)^n$$ and changing the order of summation and integration.